# MySQL ordenação muito lenta para resultados com muitos registros

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, order-by

Possuo duas tabelas, a primeira é usada para agrupar os dados da segunda com algumas informações sobre o conjunto, com o objetivo de facilitar a paginação dos conteúdos.

**Tabela 1:**

```
 - id              INT(11)    NOT NULL    UNSIGNED    AUTO_INCREMENT
 - date            DATE       NOT NULL
 - total_records   INT(11)    NOT NULL    UNSIGNED
 - created_date    TIMESTAMP
 - updated_date    TIMESTAMP

 - date_index      INDEX      date DESC
```

**Tabela 2:**

```
 - id              INT(11)    NOT NULL    UNSIGNED    AUTO_INCREMENT
 - order           INT(11)    NOT NULL    UNSIGNED
 - content         LONGTEXT   NOT NULL
 - record_id       INT(11)    NOT NULL    UNSIGNED
 - created_date    TIMESTAMP
 - updated_date    TIMESTAMP

 - content_search  FULLTEXT   content
```

A `tabela 2` se relaciona com a `tabela 1` pelo campo `record_id`.

As consulta que estou tentando fazer são as seguintes:

```
-- SQL 1
SELECT t1.`date`, t2.`id`, t2.`order`, t2.`content`
FROM `tabela1` as t1
INNER JOIN `tabela2` as t2
ON t2.`record_id` = t1.`id`
WHERE MATCH(t1.`content`) AGAINST( '"palavras chaves" @5' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY t1.`date`
LIMIT 0, 10;

-- SQL 2
SELECT t1.`date`, t2.`id`, t2.`order`, t2.`content`
FROM `tabela2` as t2
INNER JOIN `tabela1` as t1
ON t2.`record_id` = t1.`id`
WHERE MATCH(t1.`content`) AGAINST( '"palavras chaves" @5' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY t1.`date`
LIMIT 0, 10;

-- SQL 3
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t1.`date`, t2.`id`, t2.`order`, t2.`content`
    FROM `tabela2` as t2
    INNER JOIN `tabela1` as t1
    ON t2.`record_id` = t1.`id`
    WHERE MATCH(t1.`content`) AGAINST( '"palavras chaves" @5' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) as tmp
ORDER BY tmp.`date`
LIMIT 0, 10;

-- SQL 4
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t2.`id`, t2.`order`, t2.`content`, t2.`record_id`
    FROM `tabela2` as t2
    WHERE MATCH(t1.`content`) AGAINST( '"palavras chaves" @5' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) as tmp
INNER JOIN `tabela1` as t1
ON tmp.`record_id` = t1.`id`
ORDER BY tmp.`date`
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Usando um `EXPLAIN` em cada uma é possível ver que está usando ordenação por arquivo e tabelas temporárias, isto é `Using filesort` e `Using temporary`.

Para palavras chaves grandes, com cinco palavras por exemplo, a consulta e a ordenação é extremamente rápida, mesmo porque voltam poucos registros. Mas se utilizo apenas uma palavra chave o que resulta em vários registros, a consulta é rápida, mas a ordenação demora tempo demais. Em qualquer situação a consulta é rápida, mas com a ordenação essas consultas levam em média 156 segundos.

Tentei alterar a `tabela 2` desnormalizando e colocando uma cópia do campo `date` para eliminar o `INNER JOIN`. A consulta melhorou significativamente caindo para uma média de 56 segundos em consultas com uma palavra chave apenas. Mas continua com problemas na ordenação, mesmo criando um índice para a data com ordenação decrescente.

Esses problemas ocorrem no MySQL 5.6 e 5.7, pois mudei a engine de MyISAM para InnoDB. O MyISAM estava sem condição de lento e com essa mudança a buscar sem ordenação ficaram instantâneas independente da quantidade de palavras chaves. No MySQL 5.5 com em MyISAM estava muito rápido e funcionando perfeitamente em todas as situações.

Após alterar a `tabela 2` e colocar o campo de data, minhas consultas ficaram da seguinte forma

```
-- SQL 1
SELECT *
FROM `tabela2` USE INDEX (`tabela_2_date_desc`)
WHERE MATCH (`content`) AGAINST ('"palavra" @5' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
LIMIT 0 , 10;

-- SQL 2
SELECT *
FROM `tabela2`
WHERE MATCH (`content`) AGAINST ('"palavra" @5' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 10;
```

A primeira consulta retorna instantaneamente mas não está ordenado, na segunda consulta retorna com uma média de 55 segundos.

Abaixo o `EXPLAINS`

```
-- SQL 1
1   SIMPLE  tabela2     fulltext    search_content  search_content  0   const   1   100.00  Using where

-- SQL 2
1   SIMPLE  tabela2     fulltext    search_content  search_content  0   const   1   100.00  Using where; Using filesort
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a otimizar, sem usar outro tipo de banco ou mecanismo de busca como lucene?

Já tentei tirar proveito do `SQL_CACHE`.

A `tabela 1` possui cerca de 1000 registros e a `tabela 2` certa de 160.000.

Comment: Talvez a solução por um ajuste do uso da memoria por parte do MySql         http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-use.html

Comment: Ainda está com problema?

Comment: Estou sim, provavelmente devo usar outro sistema de indexação

Comment: @marcusagm implemente partition table. Já tive situações parecidas com tabela com mais de 2mi de registros.

Comment: Olá, tente criar índices para os principais Campos mais solicitados na tabela, vai melhorar ainda mais o desempenho na velocidade do resultado.

Comment: Obrigado @WilsonRosaGomes, mas o problema é justamente com um tipo de índice. Os índices necessários já foram criados.

Comment: Te fazer duas perguntas, qual á engine utilizada em seu banco, InnoDB? Os valores a serem pesquisados podem ser mapeados, ou seja, eles possuem padrões que permite a identificação via expressão regular?

Comment: Está InnoDB, como disse na pergunta, apenas por causa da versão do MySQL, pois na versão 5.7 InnoDB fica mais rápido, não entendi o porque, mas ficou. E não, a pessoa procura o que quiser em um texto, então não dá pra tratar com expressão regular. Infelizmente a solução foi usar outra ferramenta mais adequada para indexar

Answer (score 2):

Caso você insira dados nesta tabela preenchendo a coluna *date* com **now()**, experimente ordenar a *tabela2* pelo **id**, que é sequencial e provavelmente obedecerá a sequência de data.

Caso tenha importado estas tabelas desordenadas, recomendo que crie outra tabela já ordenada pela data e posteriormente revalide suas para análise de desempenho.

Comment: Opa a ideia é boa, porém tenho que ordenar as datas em decrescente. Mesmo que o ID permita ordenar as datas de forma correta, o processo usa muitas paginas de índice, deixando muito lento. A solução mesmo é usar algo mais apropriado do que o mysql para esse tipo de consulta. Obrigado pela ideia, já havia tentando =\

Comment: O id esta como índice nas tabelas também?

Comment: Sim como primary key

Comment: Sabendo de prós e contras, não é **legal** permitir ao usuário que faça uma pesquisa na base inteira pois já é previsto lentidão como a citada por você.
O que auxiliaria sua busca seria:

Comment: * <code>SELECT t1.`date`, t2.`id`, t2.`order`, t2.`content`
    FROM `tabela2` as t2
    INNER JOIN `tabela1` as t1
    ON t2.`record_id` = t1.`id`
    WHERE t1.`date` between 'DATA_INICIO' and 'DATA_FIM'</code>

Comment: e salvar na tabela temporária.

Comment: Pois é, mas como é obrigatoriamente uma pesquisa por termos nos textos, preferi usar um indexador.

Comment: e posteriormente faria a pesquisa com match neste período restrito. Atualmente trabalho com tabelas com dados de 3 anos pra cima e limitamos a pesquisa a um período de 30 dias, evitando a perda de desempenho causada quando não há limitação do período.